# Is there a Stack class in Objective C that I can import and use?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, stack, nsmutablearray

I need a stack ADT in my application. I would like to avoid making a wrapper on `NSMutableArray`; there must be an efficient implementation in Foundation somewhere.

So, how do I access it?

Comment: It's called “Xcode”, not “xCode”. Also, Xcode isn't even in the remotest way relevant to your question, which is about stack implementations.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You've got a couple of options; if you really want a stack, you could use `std::stack` from STL. Just be sure to include `#import <stack>` rename any `.m` files which use it to `.mm`.

The other option is to write an Objective-C class which either wraps `std::stack`, or provides a stack interface to `NSMutableArray`. I include this despite your wishes to the contrary, because unless you have actually profiled the code that uses `NSMutableArray`, you have absolutely **no** business complaining about its performance.

Comment: Well, my wrapper on NSMutableArray might not be efficient, you see =) .. Using STL sounds good... but, I guess I'll wrap it.

Comment: @Mazyod: It's basically implemented for you already; just use `addObject:` and `lastObject`. Make a class extension if you really want to call them `push:` and `pop`.

Comment: True, it was a very simple task. I was worried about the size of the array increasing and all that stuff, but @jonathan's answer made it clear that I shouldn't judge the code of NSMutableArray with my limited knowledge.. Thanks

Comment: @Mazyod: an interesting writeup about `NSArray` and performance: [Our Arrays, Aren't](http://ridiculousfish.com/blog/archives/2005/12/23/array/#fish_made_a_mess)

Comment: @Josh Thanks for linking to that. I was actually thinking about that as I wrote this answer, but couldn't remember where I'd seen it. Cheers!

Comment: @Jonathan Sterling: If you're trying to find a fabulously detailed explanation of some weird Mac programming minutia you saw somewhere, 95% percent of the time you can just check ridiculous_fish and NSBlog and it'll be on one of them.